# Where can I find function definition of overloaded operators of string class of c++?

Tags: c++, string, function, operator-overloading, definition

Is there any way to find already overloaded operators' functions of string class of C++ by exploring C++ libraries on my PC?
I use dev C++ to code.

Comment: Here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Comment: Did you look at `<string>`?

Comment: If you're looking for implementation, take a look for `string` (without any extension) file somewhere in your IDE installation directory. I'm not sure if it is true for Dev-C++, but Visual Studio stores C++ standard headers inside its installation folder.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? All the entities in the standard library and their behaviors are defined in detail by the C++ standard and are listed in references such as cppreference.com. You only need to know this information to use the standard library. There is no practical reason to look into the implementation.

Comment: @ChrisMM I look at string but didn't find what I needed.

Comment: @GeorgyFirsov header files do not contains implementations of function also there was no prototype declared for operators overloading for strings in its header file.

Comment: @walnut this task was given by our teacher. I wonder if he himself knows.

Comment: @AliAzlan What exactly is it that your teacher wants you to find? The standard library headers are rather complex and difficult to understand to a beginner (and as I mentioned above there is no reason to look into them if you just want to use the standard library). Without more details the task doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @AliAzlan If the task is to find all the operator overloads that the standard library defines for `std::string`, then you should *not* look into the header files, but into [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) which lists all of them.

Comment: @walnut there is no reason to look into this. It is just because our teacher was teaching us operator overloading so he gave us this task idk exactly y but may be just to  increase our knowledge. Btw thanks for ur help. 
Edit: check the comment below and my reply to it and answer it if u can.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows and Visual Studio, you can open the `xstring` file, located in your VC/include directory inside the installation path of Visual Studio. Inside that file, you can see how some operators have been overloaded, like:

```
_Myt& operator=(const _Elem *_Ptr)
    {   // assign [_Ptr, <null>)
    return (assign(_Ptr));
    }
```

Comment: What is "_Myt"? why it is not "string" for string class ? Isn't it string class operator overloading? however you are right about that xstring file and many operators' overloading functions are there but i don't know why isn't the name "string" used in operator overloading.

Comment: @AliAzlan I have not looked at the VC implementation, but `_Myt` is probably another class (template) that `std::basic_string` is inheriting from (in one way or another) and `std::string` is an alias for `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>>`. Putting implementation details into inherited classes is very common in the standard library (and outside of it) for different reasons. As I mentioned in my comments under the question, without having a good and broad understanding of the language, the standard library implementation is not going to make much sense to a reader.